# in React for an array of buttons, how to change color after click while also record which button/buttons is/are clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a child component which is a single button that change color after click with state update. However I also need to identify in an array of such buttons which one is being clicked. Code in [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-adjhr8?file=button.js) or below. How can I do so? If I have an action on the child component, then how can I properly call onclick on the parent component?

button.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css'

class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           clicked: false
        }
    }

    changeColor=()=>{
       this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})
    }

    render(){
        let btn_class = this.state.clicked ? "redButton" : "whiteButton";

        return (
             <button className={btn_class} onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this)}>
                  {this.props.name}
             </button>
        )
    }
}
export default Button;
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import Button from './button.js'

const btns= ['button1','button2','button3']
const n = btns.length

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      clickedBtn : "",
      btnStyle: new Array(n)
    };
  }

handleClick= (index) => 
  {
    alert(index)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            {btns.map((btn, index) => (
                      <Button 
                        name={btn} 
                        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,index)}/>
                    ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic handler function for this.. There is also no reason to bind methods to a class now - you no longer have to do this if you're using arrow functions to define your methods.

Lastly, you should probably use the callback that `setState` provides to call the `onClick` prop inside of the `Button` component.

*More on `setState` callback:* the way you use the callback is like this:

```
setState({ some: "newState"}, function() { /* this is the callback function */ })
```

***Using `setState` callback:***

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      clicked: false
    };
  }

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ 
      clicked: !this.state.clicked 
    }, () => { // Should prob use the callback that setState provides
      if (this.props.onClick) this.props.onClick() 
    });
  };

  render() {
    let btn_class = this.state.clicked ? "redButton" : "whiteButton";

    return (
      <button className={btn_class} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.props.name}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

const btns= ['button1','button2','button3']
const n = btns.length

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      clickedBtn: "",
      btnStyle: new Array(n)
    };
  }

  handleClick = index => {
    alert(index);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.clickedTag);
    return (
      <div>
        {btns.map((btn, index) => (
          <Button name={btn} onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.whiteButton{
  background-color: white
}

.redButton{
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

***NOT using `setState` callback:***

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      clicked: false
    };
  }

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ 
      clicked: !this.state.clicked 
    });
    if (this.props.onClick) this.props.onClick()     
  };

  render() {
    let btn_class = this.state.clicked ? "redButton" : "whiteButton";

    return (
      <button className={btn_class} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.props.name}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

const btns= ['button1','button2','button3']
const n = btns.length

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      clickedBtn: "",
      btnStyle: new Array(n)
    };
  }

  handleClick = index => {
    alert(index);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.clickedTag);
    return (
      <div>
        {btns.map((btn, index) => (
          <Button name={btn} onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.whiteButton{
  background-color: white
}

.redButton{
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works well. Just want to clarify the meaning of "use the callback that setState provides to call the onClick prop inside of the Button component" – do you mean in the Button component do some sort of onClick={this.props.onClick} or exactly like the one you've showed?

Comment: I meant exactly like the one I showed. `setState` is asynchronous - so using the callback that `setState` provides ensures that when the callback runs, your `state` will contain the new values. You can find more on that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) - and there is a pretty good explanation [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710). I have added another snippet to my answer to show the difference in using `setState` callback vs not using it. Notice how in the second example the button changes color after the alert.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that, at last you will have clicked button value in the clickedButton object.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css'

class Button extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           clicked: false
        }
    }

    changeColor=()=>{
       this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})
this.props.onButtonClick(this.props.index)
    }

    render(){
        let btn_class = this.state.clicked ? "redButton" : "whiteButton";

        return (
             <button className={btn_class} onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this)}>
                  {this.props.name}
             </button>
        )
    }
}
export default Button;
```

index.js

```
class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          clickedBtn : {},
          btnStyle: new Array(n)
        };
      }

    handleClick= (index) => 
      {
        let clickedBtn = this.state.clickedBtn 
        if(clickedBtn[index]){
           delete clickedBtn[index]
        } else{
           clickedBtn[index]= true
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
                {btns.map((btn, index) => (
                          <Button 
                            name={btn} 
                        index={index}
                         onButtonClick={this.handleClick}/>
                        ))}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```